# How to reload the column view list using the jquery.columnview-1.2.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have used the jquery plugin for building an ui as mentioned in the website:

http://christianyates.com/blog/jquery/finder-column-view-hierarchical-lists-jquery

below the columns list I have a button : Add Client group.

On click of the Add client group the below mentioned jquery method is invoked:

```
var addClientGroupDialog = $("#client-group-add-dialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "Add Client group",
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            "Save": function () {
                var clientGroup = getClientGroupId();
                var name = $("#add-clientgroup-name").val();
                var reference = $("#add-clientgroup-sap").val();

                if (name.length > 0) {
                    $.post(addClientGroupUrl, { clientGroup: clientGroup, name: name, sapNumber: reference },
                    function (response) {
                        if (response.Success) {
                            //window.location.reload();
                            $("#client-group-add-dialog").dialog("close");
                        } else {
                            alert(response.Message);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("Please enter a name for this Client group first.");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The above method is called from another AddUser.js file.

on success of the method, I want to reload the column view UI (in short I want to reload the column view list) without any page refresh.

Can you please help me in resolving the issue.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro